# The button doesn't change background color and doesn't hover

Tags: html, css

I'm a total rookie in coding so it may be an easy mistake but please help me :)

I made a button in css and I want its color to be main color, but it doesn't work. The button doesn't change the color at all. Also, it doesn't change the color in hover, and the border radius also doesn't work.

Thats the code:

```
.btn {
  padding: 18px 24px 18px 24px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: $color-main;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: darken($color-main, 3%);
  color: #000000;
}
```

html of a whole section:

```
<section class="splash">
  <div class="page-intro">
    <h1 class="main-title">Witaj na mojej stronie!</h1>
    <h2 class="main-subtitle">Test</h2>
    <a class="btn btn-solid" href="#about">o mnie</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Hope Y'all help :))

Comment: Could you share the related html?

Comment: Kindly add html, so we could run your code here.

Comment: your code is working. see example: https://jsfiddle.net/ya7tzcq6/1/. You are using scss, do you have the variable $color-main set up?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `!important` next to the color you want to use can solve your problem.Like this:

```
.btn{
background-color:red !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harsh2690/oh4spgq1/) with darken

```
$blue: #1e90ff; 
.btn  {   padding: 18px 24px 18px 24px;   
          font-size: 18px;  
          background-color: $blue;   
          color: #000000;   
          font-family: sans-serif; 
          border-radius: 30px; 
      }
 .btn:hover  {
 background-color: darken($blue,12);        
 color:#ffffff; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are a beginner, SCSS or SASS is not used in the same way as CSS, if you are only using html and css only, replace darken (...) with a darker color simply. if you use SASS / SCSS the code works fine with me

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this. It works.

```
.btn {
  padding: 18px 24px 18px 24px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: $color-main;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 30px;
  outline: none;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

html

```
<button class="btn">click me</button>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change the main-color to darker?

Comment: I think you have to define color-main.